# What does ./outputfile mean in Terminal

Tags: xcode, terminal

I'm new to using Terminal for compiling code. In the following

```
 gcc inputfile.m -o outputfile  

 ./outputfile
```

What does the ./ mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`./outputfile` tells Bash (the program that runs the Terminal) to run the file `outputfile` which is located in the current directory (`./`)

Bash can run any file, whether is a compiled file (like you case) or a script.

Comment: So to access a file in the current directory, you have to do ./ XXX, instead of in Windows, you can just type XXX

Answer (score 0):

That is your compiled program. The line `./outputfile` is calling the executable you created. It may seem a little strange that you have to do this in your case because you are only using 1 input file, but imagine that you are creating a bigger program with a many files that all need to be compiled together.

```
gcc inputfile1.m inputfile2.m class1.m class2.m main.m -o outputfile
```

All those files would be compiled and put into outputfile.